# Date Time Conversion Issue In Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a web application using ASP.NET & SQL Server 2008.

In that application I have one form where I want to show records into GridView depends on two dates: From Date and To Date. There are two TextBoxes in which I have used Calender Extender.

When I run the application on my machine it works properly, but when I try to run the application on another machine I am facing a DateTime conversion issue.

It gives me an exception - `Input string was not in a correct format`

Can you please tell me some technique so that I can run my application on any machine, and with any DateTime format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check machine datetime format

Comment: Where do you get that error? How is this related to SQL Server? Did you hard-code the string format in the text boxes? If so, you have to parse them using the hard-coded format, or the corresponding CultureInfo

Comment: Hi Panagiotis Kanavos,I did not hard coded the string format in the text boxes.But i have to compare the entered date into text box with the date which is present in SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've bumped my head on this a few times, particularly when deploying to another machine that doesn't have the same locale as my development machine. The best technique I've found to avoid this issue is to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So what I usually do is set my culture equal to a constant culture (in my case "en-GB") and then set a fixed date format.

From the above link an example of this would be:

```
// Allow a leading space in the date string. 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, 
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);
```

If my case, I'd change the enUS culture to enGB and change the date format to what I'm expecting like "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm". What's also good about the TryParse also is that if you encounter an error you can either attempt to correct it or log it (for example a misformatted date in the DB).

Answer (score 0):

Please check CultureInfo.InvariantCulture